# How to add confidence interval to linearly extrapolated data in google sheets?

Tags: confidence-interval, extrapolation

I have a daily sells data of number of units sold in last few years. I linearly extrapolated it in the google sheet for next 1 year. How can I add the confidence interval to the extrapolated data? Can I simply use the below definition of confidence interval and calculate lower and upper bound?

[CI Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvpO7.png)